# Conjugation between rings of biphenyls

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance

I thought since both phenyl rings are not coplanar, the resonance between them is not possible. But my book says the following:

> Resonance effect is **partially** nullified

Partially nullified means resonance is relatively weak but it's taking place

Comment: What book are you referring to, please cite your source.

Comment: Its  M. S. Chauhan

Comment: Looking at amazon, there are many books by that author- are you looking at a specific one? A title and page ref would be helpful

Comment: It's in solution manual of advanced problem in organic chemistry in 10th edition on pg no.264

Comment: Rule of thumb: **DOI** for a paper, **ISBN** for a book. This makes things easier.

Comment: If I weren't a mod I might have vtc'd as unclear, as I have no idea what "partial nullification" of resonance means. Is there any explanation or justification in the book?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what "weak resonance" is. To me it is something like a boolean, it is either there or not. It sound like "she is a little bit pregnant":)

Comment: But that's what the book says

Comment: To get a qualitative idea of the "amount of resonance", it would be interesting to compare the absorption spectrum of polyphenylenes (where all phenyl rings are free to rotate) and polyfluorenes (where phenyl rings are pairwise fused into a coplanar arrangement). I'm fairly sure the latter can absorb higher wavelength photons, suggesting a smaller HOMO-LUMO gap due to increased delocalization of the $\pi$ electrons.

Comment: @andselisk that's not the case. If you twist the rings you still get orbital overlap and resonance. The overlap just isn't as good so the effect is weak. Otherwise for practical reasons resonance between aromatic rings wouldn't exist, since most of the time they are not perfectly planar aligned.

Comment: @DSVA Sounds like an answer, go ahead, post it.

Comment: @DSVA but isn't the coplanarity the topmost condition for resonance

Comment: @andselisk I will do little bit later when I got time including an example.

Comment: Coplanarity is in no way a condition for [resonance](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/R/R05326.html). In its widest scope resonance simply means, how delocalised is a certain system. In biphenyl, you still have two highly delocalised aromatic rings. The overlap, and further delocalisation of those two aromatic systems might not be as large as in a planar system, but it is certainly there. || Please [edit] in the complete citation to the quoted statement, so that it can be seen in context. You might want to tag it [tag:erratum], too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I thought since both phenyl rings are not coplanar, the resonance between them is not possible.

This is not correct. If the rings are coplanar you get the best orbital overlap and the strongest resonance effect, while if you twist it the effect will be smaller but still present until you are at an dihedral angle of 90°, where no overlap can take place.

Let us look at phenyl-tetrazine. The phenyl substituent loweres the LUMO of the tetrazine through conjugation and raises the HOMO. The most favored confomer is the planar one, so the ideal system to study this. If it's correct that resonance only takes place at a planar conformation we should see a sudden jump in LUMO energy between planar conformation and any other and for all angles not equal to 0° the LUMO level should be the same.

[image]

In addition resonance is stabilizing, so the energy should drop rapidly between non-planar and planar.

Calculated energies (M06-2X/6-311+(d,p)) while twisting the bond looks like this:

[image]

So the energy goes up continuously if we twist the phenyl ring, there's no jump in energy. Since there's basically no steric effect, unlike in biphenyl, the energy is most likely only influenced by resonance.

Let us look at the HOMO level. I just picked some angles:

[image]

As expected the HOMO is raised in case of planar conformation in contrast to 90°, where we expect no overlap but we can clearly see that there's an influence on the HOMO at nearly every angle getting much stronger if we get near planarity.

Since the HOMO is completely localized at the tetrazine even in the planar form let's look at the HOMO-3 as an example. This orbital is part of the conjugated aromatic system and looks like this if the angle is 0°. Of course orbital energies will get shifted if we twist the rings and finding "the same" orbital is hard, but I'll show the orbital with the same symmetry at the tetrazine.

Here's the picture for 0°, a nice conjugated system:
[image]

Here's the picture for 90°, there's no conjugation with the pi-system, little bit with some, I assume, sigma* orbitals.
[image]

Now here for 15,30 and 60°:
[image]
[image]
[image]

We can see quite nicely that the orbital in case of 15 and 30° still looks quite similar to the one at 0°, while the one at 60° already looks quite like the one at 90°, with a little bit of orbital in para position at the phenyl ring. Showing that there's a gradual loss of conjugation.

In addition, if the conjugation would be possible only at exact 0° dihedral angle then two things could happen: Either we won't see the effect of conjugation ever, since the molecules move all the time and if rotation around that bond is possible then the chance that the molecule is at exact 0° is basically zero. But we know that conjugation exists. Or the planar conformation would be much more stable due to the conjugation and it would be exact 0° all the time, but from experiments we actually know that those bonds rotate quite well.

> coplanarity the topmost condition for resonance –

The most important condition is an overlap between the orbitals, this usually works best if planar, but it most certainly doesn't have to be planar.